# Does PHP include_path use working directory as fallback?

Tags: php

I have a PHP script executed via `php /dir2/main.php` while on `/dir1` as a working directory. They both have identical file and the `include_path` is set to `/dir2` however if the file is missing I would expect `require('file')` to throw an error but instead `/dir1/file` is loaded even though it's not in the `include_path`

`var_dump(get_include_path()) => string(5) "/dir2"`

It seems that the working directory is used as fallback but I couldn't find any mention in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

**Edit:** Here's a representation of the directory structure and the code used.

```
/dir1
    file.txt (I am 1)
/dir2
    file.txt (I am 2)
    main.php
```

main.php

```
<?php
set_include_path(__DIR__);
require('file.txt');
```

bash:

```
> cd /dir1
> php /dir2/main.php
> rm /dir2/file.txt
> php /dir2/main.php
```

output:

```
I am 2
I am 1
```

Comment: Is `.` (dot) in your include path? That would mean "current directory".

Comment: no, only `dir2` @JohnConde

Comment: `echo ini_get('include_path');`

Comment: both `ini_get` and `get_include_path` show `dir2` only @AbraCadaver

Comment: I'm able to reproduce what you're saying so yes, it does seem that PHP will look in the current working directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. [From the `include()` documentation:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. **If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.** The include construct will emit an E_WARNING if it cannot find a file; this is different behavior from require, which will emit an E_ERROR.

And as noted, `include` and `require` are identical in how they look up files, and only differ in how they react if a file is not found.

Comment: Thank you, the section I linked isn't clear about this. There also should be a way to prevent this other than setting `open_basedir` which may have other implications.

Comment: @resu: Prevent this by using a path, always, e.g. with `__DIR__`.